# Meteor, query Collections based on ids retrieved from another collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have 2 collections.

```
ItemList = new Mongo.Collection('items');
BorrowerDetails = new Mongo.Collection('borrow');

ItemList.insert({
    brand: "brand-Name",
    type: "brand-Type",
    ._id: id
});

BorrowerDetails.insert({
    key: "ItemList.id", //equals to .id of the ItemList Collection
    name : "borrowerName"
});
```

Question !
How can i retrieve records from the BorrowerDetails Collection based on a certain type from the ItemList Collection.

ex. Retrieve all records from the BorrowerDetails Collection where key is equals to the id of a record on the ItemList Collection whose type is equals to "Desktop".

```
return BorrowerDetails.find(
    { key : 
        ItemList.find(
            { type : 'Desktop' },
            { fields: {'_id':1 } }
        )
    }
); //error!
```

Comment: When you use NOSQL database, you should not think to join. Instead you select it 2 times.

Comment: Sir Can you explain briefly? :)

Comment: ok give me a minute...

Comment: -----Thanks sir------

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that I don't have nodejs right now in my laptop, so might have several errors since I am not able to test it.

First, Create a publication file (eg. server\publications\borrowPub.js). inside the file, you should create a publication method. The logic here is simple, get the itemid array first, and then pass it as parameter in [Mongo select $in.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)

```
Meteor.publish('queryBorrowerTypeDesktop', function(criteria)
{

   var itemArr = ItemList.find( { type : 'Desktop' },
                             { fields: {'_id':1 } });
   if(itemArr){
    //itemArr found, so do a select in using the array of item  id we retrieved earlier
    var borrowers = BorrowerDetails.find({ key: { $in: itemArr } });
    return borrowers;
   }else{
     //found nothing- so return nothing
     return [] 
   }
});
```

Second, in the router :

```
Router.route('/test', {
  name: 'test',
 action: function()
 {
   //change accordingly.
 },
 waitOn: function()
 {//subscribe from publisher that we just created...
  return [
    Meteor.subscribe('queryBorrowerTypeDesktop') 
  ];
 },
 data: function() {
 if(Meteor.userId())
 {
     // also include the sorting and limit so your page will not crash. change accordingly. 
     return {
       borrowerDetails: BorrowerDetails.find({},{sort: {name: -1},        limit: 30}),
  }
  }
 }
});
```

Note that in data, BorrowerDetails.find() does not need to filter by anything because it has been filtered during the subscribe, which has been cached in MiniMongo in your browser.

Comment: Sir what is qty in var borrowers = BorrowerDetails.find({ qty: { $in: itemArr } })